# Fetch the values from the post request body

Tags: jmeter

I want to fetch two values from the post request body. How can I do it in JMeter?

`request-url: http://localhost:8080/webimpactclean/progress/createTrialUnits.do`

```
POST data:
org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN=21b148643555da16dcd3ca2f32439b88&fakeSubmitButton=Submit&patientMonitoringFlagCopyDown=&enteredScreeningCopyDown=&enteredBaselineCopyDown=&enteredTreatmentCopyDown=&completedTreatmentCopyDown=&enteredFollowUpCopyDown=&completedFollowUpCopyDown=&create%5B0%5D=on&displayUnitNo%5B0%5D=1167&trialUnitReference%5B0%5D=PERFT1167&primaryInvestigatorShortNameDisabled%5B0%5D=&primaryInvestigatorShortName%5B0%5D=&primaryInvestigator%5B0%5D=&primaryCentreShortNameDisabled%5B0%5D=&primaryCentreShortName%5B0%5D=&primaryCentre%5B0%5D=&primaryCentreShortNameTemp%5B0%5D=&primaryCentreTemp%5B0%5D=&centreDepartmentName%5B0%5D=&centreName%5B0%5D=&centreLocationAddress%5B0%5D=&centreLocationAddressTemp%5B0%5D=&addressLine1%5B0%5D=&addressLine2%5B0%5D=&addressLine3%5B0%5D=&addressLine4%5B0%5D=
```

And I want to fetch the `displayUnitNo%5B0%5D=1167&trialUnitReference%5B0%5D=PERFT1167` values which are `1167` and `PERFT1167`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally people want to extract data from **responses**, it doesn't make any sense to extract data from the request because you're supposed to have this data already. If you want to have different data for each user/iteration - you should [parameterize](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/) the request body.

Whatever, if you want to save the values from the request into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you could do this using i.e. [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the code like:

```
def parameters = sampler.getArguments().argumentsAsMap

vars.put('trialUnitReference', parameters.get('trialUnitReference[0]'))
vars.put('displayUnitNo', parameters.get('displayUnitNo[0]'))
```